# Создание и уничтожение форм. Освобождение переменных.

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты!
По нажатию кнопки создаю форму и отображаю:

> newform:=Tnewform.Create(Self);  
> newform.ShowModal;

Потом закрываю новую форму и снова жму на кнопочку. И так несколько раз. Вопросы:

```
 1. Выходит, что одна и та же форма создалась несколько раз?
 2. Нужно ли уничтожать форму при её закрытии? Или нужно уничтожать её при закрытии главной формы?
 3. Если я не ошибаюсь, у каждого компонента и переменной есть методы для уничтожения, нужно ли уничтожать всё при закрытии приложения?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да. У Вас будет несколько копий (экземпляров) одной формы
2. Желательно уничтожать форму тогда, когда она Вам больше не нужна. Но никто не мешает ее переиспользовать.
3. Все компоненты, которые добавлены на форму, не нужно уничтожать ручками - форма их сама удалит автоматически при своем удалении. Компоненты, которые не привязаны к форме, нужно удалять самостоятельно. Также нужно удалять переменные, которым это требуется (к примеру, TStringList).

Comment: Не переменные, а объекты.

Comment: Ваше замечание не совсем корректное. Есть и переменные, которые нужно "удалять". К примеру, если с помощью malloc выделить памяти. Это же не объект (да, я знаю, что не все делают ручное управление, но всякое бывает).

Можно открыть файл. Дескриптор нужно закрыть за собой. Дескриптор это не совсем переменная, но и не объект (Хотя это объект ядра).

А ещё есть интерфейсы и много много другого. Поэтому, я считаю, переменная - самое удачное слово.

Comment: Этот список Вы должны сами знать. Удаляйте те объекты, которые сами создали. Но если утечки есть, а где - неведомо, то можно попросить делфи подсказать - в последних версиях встроена тулза. [Детальнее](http://delphinotes.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/find-memory-leaks-in-delphi/).

Comment: @KoVadim вы все верно написали. В таком случае пример пример в ответе не удачный (TStringList).

Утечки можно искать с помощью FastMM.

Comment: В последних версиях делфи FastMM встроен:)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делаю так:

```
NewForm := TNewForm.Create(Self); // или Create(nil);
try
  NewForm.ShowModal;
finally
  NewForm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Ууж если так, тогда пишите ещё красивее:

    with TNewForm.Create(Self) do
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;

Comment: destroy ручками вызывается только в исключительных случаях, когда Вы четко понимаете, что делаете. Во всех остальных случаях `Free` или FreeAndNil(имя_переменной)` - который ещё и зануляет переменную.

Comment: @АлександрЪ Метод `Free` объявлен в `TObject`. Выглядит он так:



   procedure TObject.Free;


   begin


     if Self <> nil then


     Destroy;


   end;



Метод `Free` вызывает `Destroy`, однако ничего страшного не случается, если вдруг объект забыли создать или вызвали ранее `FreeAndNil`.